# iv-user vs. REMOTE_USER Apache

Tags: apache-httpd

Is setting the iv-user header in an HTTP request the same as setting the REMOTE_USER variable? If one application sets the user id in the iv-user header is there a way for Apache put it into the REMOTE_USER variable? Or am I mixing things up?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're confusing things. Take look at the table in this [IBM doc on IV Headers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/el/SSPREK_7.0.0/com.ibm.isam.doc_80/ameb_webplugin_guide/concept/con_ivhdr_authe.html).

> Iv-user - The short name of the Access Manager user. Defaults to unauthenticated if the client is unauthenticated (unknown).

They're not the same based on what I'm reading in that article.

Comment: Oh, IBM! A typo on your website. I'll correct it here, because I can.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. So is it safe to say that iv-headers is something proprietary from IBM and the REMOTE_USER variable is Apache stuff ?

Comment: That' would be my take.